# PHP and dynamic number formatting

Tags: php, format

I have looked for a way to do this and have not found it.

I have values read from MySQL: 100.00, 85.50, 97.00, 71.33

I want them to display as: 100, 85.5, 97, 71.33

I see number_format() that specifies FIXED decimal places, but I need a sort of 'significant digits format'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use (float)$number;

```
$a = '100.00';
$b = 73.50;
$c = 71.33;

echo (float)$a; // 100
echo (float)$b; // 73.5
echo (float)$c; // 71.33
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use floatval function  to get your required output. just check below code.

```
var_dump(floatval('100.00'));
var_dump(floatval('85.50'));
var_dump(floatval('71.33'));
```